# I am categorizing the data, but my results are no the expectable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, series

I am categorizing the data, but my results are no the expectable.

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\gabri\Downloads\credit_scoring_eng.csv')

def assign_status(row):
    test='Negado'

    # Desempregado
    if row['income_type']=='unemployed':
        test='N'
        
# Já devedor
    elif row['debt']==1:
        test='N'
#Relação de renda e filhos.
    elif row['total_income']>28000 & row['children']==0:
        test='Y'
# Teste recuperado
    elif row['total_income']>31000 & row['children']==1:
        test='Y'
# Teste desconhecido
    elif row['total_income']>34000 & row['children']==2:
        test='Y'
    elif row['total_income']>37000 & row['children']==3:
        test='Y'
    elif row['total_income']>40000 & row['children']==4:
        test='Y'
    elif row['total_income']>43000 & row['children']==5:
        test='Y'
    else:
        test='N'
    return test
df['results']=df.apply(assign_status, axis=1)
print(df.head(10))
```

Here's the results (Look at the line 1):

```
   children  days_employed  dob_years            education  education_id  \

1         1    4024.803754         44  secondary_education             1   


       family_status  family_status_id gender income_type  debt  total_income  \

1            married                 0      F    employee     0     17932.802   

                               purpose results  

1                         car purchase  Y
```

Looking at total_income we can see that he is < than 31000, the minimum to recieve a Y with one children, why this is happening (recieving a Y instead of a N)?

(recieving a Y instead of a N in the new column)

Comment: Ahh, overlooked something, replace the '&' in the `if`/`elif` statements with `and` and retest

Comment: Worked! 
Thank you very much, @HWW,, why this thing happen?

Comment: While we both know `&` and `and` mean the same, to python they are not. From [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-and-and-in-python/) `and is a Logical AND that returns True if both the operands are true whereas ‘&’ is a bitwise operator in Python that acts on bits and performs bit by bit operation.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, overlooked something, replace the '&' in the `if/elif` statements with `and` and retest

thanks for the accept